# Oracle RAC , Do I need XA driver?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, driver, cluster-computing, xa

I have Oracle 11g, configured to use Real Application Cluster (RAC) and storage.

I thought XA is for 2PC transactions , for multiple data sources/managers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In theory you wouldn't have to use any different driver for Oracle RAC, because it should resolve clustering and scaling behind the scenes.

You need XA transactions when you have several different data sources which should be used under one transaction.

Do you experience any issues when using non-XA driver with Oracle RAC?

Comment: Thanks!

"Do you experience any issues when using non-XA driver with Oracle RAC?"

Until now I had no tests with RAC at all. I work on test environment(no RAC) and RAC is expected on production environment. So I just prepare myself :)

Comment: Unfortunately life is not that easy. The client/midtier is actually controlling if XA is used. Under the covers it will invoke an XA_start call if the corresponding data source is configured. A lot of users are actually not aware if they use XA or not. They might have configured XA and use XA even when local transactions would be sufficient. You can check with the view v$global_transactions if there are any XA transactions.